# Groovy markupBuilder updating parent node

Tags: grails, groovy, markupbuilder

I'm building xml using MarkupBuilder and wonder how can I update a parent attribute when creating a child node. Assuming the number of child elements cannot be calculated when building the parent element.

```
 def writer = new StringWriter()
 def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)

 xml.parent(totalDuration: 'should be: some of all child duration') {
     child(duration: '1')
     child(duration: '2') 
...  
 }
```

Is there an elegant way of accessing the parent node from a child node?

Thanks
Tal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an elegant way of accessing the parent node from a child node?

Not with a MarkupBuilder, which generates the XML in a streaming fashion (it has already written the parent element's opening tag to the output stream before calling the nested closure).  But you could use a [DOMBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/index.html?groovy/xml/DOMBuilder.html) to build up a DOM tree in memory, then fill in the total using the DOM API, and finally serialize the DOM tree including the total attribute:

```
import groovy.xml.*
import groovy.xml.dom.*
import org.w3c.dom.*

def dom = DOMBuilder.newInstance(false, true)
Element parent = dom.parent() {
  child(duration:'1')
  child(duration:'2')
}
use(DOMCategory) {
  parent.setAttributeNS(null, "totalDuration",
                        parent.xpath('sum(child/@duration)'))
}

def xmlString = XmlUtil.serialize(parent)
```

The DOMBuilder should work the same as a MarkupBuilder as long as you're not using `mkp.yield` or `mkp.yieldUnescaped` inside the closure.  If you need to use these then you'd have to build up the XML string without the `totalDuration` attribute, then re-parse it into a DOM, add the extra attribute and re-serialize.