# create xml markupBuilder based on external variables

Tags: xml, groovy, markupbuilder

I have seen in plenty of websites the common use of MarkupBuilder xml creator. For example:

```
def xmlWriter = new StringWriter()
def xmlMarkup = new MarkupBuilder(xmlWriter)
xmlMarkup.movie(id: "2", "the godfather")
println(xmlWriter.toString())
```

Will give something like this:

```
<movie id='2'>the godfather</movie>
```

My question is: ¿Is there a good way to use MarkupBuilder to compose an xml using variables taken from a method?

I have manage to add the root access with this code:

```
createXml(root){
    def xmlWriter = new StringWriter()
    def xmlMarkupBuilder = new MarkupBuilder(xmlStringWriter)
    xmlMarkupBuilder.createNode(root)
    xmlMarkupBuilder.nodeCompleted(null,root)
}
```

But I'm pretty sure there must be another clean way to do it. How can I add a new node if I only know the name of the parent node?

I ended up doing this with java DocumentBuilder,

```
    XmlData(xmlPath, rootNodeName){
       this.xmlPath = xmlPath
       xmlDoc =    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument()
       def rootNode=xmlDoc.createElement(rootNodeName)
       xmlDoc.appendChild(rootNode)
   }

    def addNode(parentNodeName,nodeName,nodeValue,attributes){
       def newNode = xmlDoc.createElement(nodeName)
       if(nodeValue!=null){
          def newTextNode = xmlDoc.createTextNode(nodeValue)
          newNode.appendChild(newTextNode)
       }
       if(attributes!=null){
          attributes.each{key,value ->
            newNode.setAttribute($key,$value)
          }
       }
       def nodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(parentNodeName)
       nodeList.item(nodeList.getLength()-1).appendChild(newNode)
   }
```

but if there is a cleaner way to do this with MarkupBuilder or MarkupBuilderHelper, I would preffer to use that one. The code I would like to get is:

Input:

```
        def xmlWriter = new XmlWriter("rootNode")
        xmlWriter.addNode("rootNode","",null)
        xmlWriter.addNode("rootNode","child2",null)
        xmlWriter.addNode("child1","child11","text1")
        xmlWriter.addNode("child1","child12","text2")
        xmlWriter.addNode("child2","child21","text3")
        xmlWriter.addNode("child2","child22","text4")
```

Methods:

```
class XmlWriter{
    createXml(root){
    def xmlWriter = new StringWriter()
    def xmlMarkupBuilder = new MarkupBuilder(xmlStringWriter)
    xmlMarkupBuilder.createNode(root)
    xmlMarkupBuilder.nodeCompleted(null,root)
    }

    def addNode(parentNodeName,nodeName,nodeValue,attributes){
       ???
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<rootNode>
  <child1>
     <child11>test1</child11>
     </child12>test2</child12>
  </child1>
  <child2>
     <child21>test3</child21>
     </child22>test4</child22>
  </child2>
</rootNode>
```

Note: I don't take into account that could exist several items in nodeList items because in my xml this is not possible at the present moment.

Comment: Can you show example input, example method call and required output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one method to do what I think you want...

Given some XML:

```
def xml = '''<root>
            |    <node>
            |        <anotherNode some="thing">
            |            Woo
            |        </anotherNode>
            |        <stuff>
            |        </stuff>
            |    <node>
            |    </node>
            |        <anotherNode some="thing">
            |            Woo
            |        </anotherNode>
            |        <stuff>
            |        </stuff>
            |    </node>
            |</root>'''.stripMargin()
```

and given the name of the parent node, the name of the new child node, it's attributes and text content:

```
def parentName = 'stuff'
def nodeName = 'things'
def nodeContent = 'text'
def attributes = [ tim: 'yates' ]
```

We can parse the XML with `XmlParser`

```
import groovy.xml.*

def root = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
```

And then find all nodes called `parentName` and append a new node to each of them:

```
root.'**'.findAll { it.name() == parentName }
         .each {
             it.appendNode(new Node(it, nodeName, attributes, nodeContent))
         }
```

Then, printing out the xml should show they're there:

```
println XmlUtil.serialize(root)
```

Comment: OK. I think this is the correct answer because as says this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19157351/1924923) you can't use MarkupBuilder to search root node, and in extension, any node. So if the xml si growing step by step with add calls, it must be modified with an XmlSluper (or similar) class, that keeps the whole xml structure in memory.